Equations in display style not centered but with an indent
I'd like to use display style-equations but I don't want them to be centered. Instead, I'd like to have them left-aligned with 2 cm indent. Is this possible?

Welcome to TeX SE. Have a look at the fleqn class option for this matter.

Sure. You can use fleqn option and change \mathindent to suit your needs.
Keep in mind that you need to use LaTeX syntax for display math (i.e. \[ ... \] or amsmath environments for fleqn to work, otherwise if you use $$ syntax the equation will remain centered. See this post for more details.
In the following MWE, if you don't want your equations numbered, you can use equation* instead of equation
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\mathindent}{2cm}
\begin{document}
    
\lipsum[13]
    \begin{equation}
        a + b = c
    \end{equation}
    

\lipsum[13]
\end{document}



Thanks. So the $$...$$ doesn't work. It only works with \begin{equation} ... \end{equation} ?

@fswaan Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?

@fswaan is always preferable to use amsmath environments or \[ math \] instead of $$. One of the issues is that spacing with $$ is messed up in some cases, like this one. Furthermore, if you don't want the numbering, you can use equation* instead.

Thanks. Wil be using [] from now on.

@fswaan You have discovered one of the many reasons why $$..$$ should not be used in LaTeX.
